# Alternative to activeResource.save (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, post

Just being very basic here. I'm trying to post an activeResource as Json and recover it on the other side. At present, I seem to be able to send JSON but not recreate it into an Object of my choice.

---

I've tried my hand at generating a post request with Json in Ruby.

There are 2 parts to be aware of, The active resource on client side and the controller handling the incoming request. The errors usually come down to 406 (request not acceptable) or 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
I suppose the basic question is how can I fix these?

Here is my active resource class.

```
class UserRequest < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://localhost:3008"
  self.format = :json
  #do not define defs as 'self'.whatever


  def post_me
    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://127.0.0.1:3008/user_requests.xml'),
                              {'url' =>'www.stackoverflow.com', 'depth' => '50'})
  end
end
#Just to clarify. If im sending Json, I change the URI to .json and If I'm using xml, I   #remove the self.format because active resource is XML by default
```

and here is line in controller which turns it to active record. controllers titled UserRequestsController

```
def add_request
    @user_request = UserRequest.new(params[:user_request])
.
.
. end
```

route is

```
 match '/user_requests(.:format)' => 'user_requests#add_request', :via =>:post
```

Now a few things before everyone face palms and goes mad at me.

I'm aware that in the def for add_request I'm missing JSON.parse. This is because when I include it I get  500 and an uninitialized constant error on server side. The gem is definitely installed and I'm not the only one whos had the problem but sadly no fixes.

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=4654
http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=28301

So theres one question is how do i fix the parse so that it works the way I want to as I'm assuming the 406 is because its receiving Json but not sending it.
This would be ideal however if its not possible or someone can think of a reason why I should use XML, then perhaps they could take a look at this and tell me why I might be getting it on server side

```
Started POST "/user_requests.xml" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jul 14 09:38:34 +0100 2011
  Processing by UserRequestsController#add_request as XML
  Parameters: {"depth"=>"50", "url"=>"www.stackoverflow.com"}
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "user_requests" WHERE ("user_requests"."url" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 18ms (Views: 3.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Just one last thing is the reasoin I'm not using .save is because the lead on my intern program doesn't like and says its not fit for purpose.

Comment: Something I just tried there. posting with user_request.json and not including JSON.parse on controller side gives the same unprocessable entity problem

Comment: If you use `JSON.parse` (or any other method of `JSON`) you'll have to load the JSON standard library with `require 'json'`.

Comment: @Koraktor I put gem json in the gemfile. require json seems to give file not found. If the Json.parse worked, I would still get 422 instead of 406

Comment: On another note. If i use .as_json for the user request, it seems to accept it but cannot process it into a UserRequest object. cant use .save either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Try modifying your "add_request" method like this:

```
def add_request
    @user_request = UserRequest.new(params[:user_request])
    format.json { render :json => @user_request, :status => :created, :location => @user_request }
end
```

Comment: There was already a bunch of formats in there my friend, They were cut out of my example unfortunately. In the end, it turned out to be the :user_request params. I should have been passing the values manually. so :myint, :myString.   You get top marks for spotting it though.